# jQuery/HTML DOM method parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, parameters

I have no idea what exactly to call these, considering I'm a newbie at jQuery (but I wish to learn more).

How can I create a jQuery plugin or maybe even a method in the DOM that you can have parameters like THIS:

"foo":"bar",
"foo2":1.5,

A working example (with jQuery Transit):

$('.box').transition(**{ x: '200px', y: '20px' }**);

What are these kind of parameters called (if anything) and how can I use them for plugins, or even the DOM? (I would really prefer the DOM though).

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: this is not very difficult to learn just follow the basics in the api documentations: http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: They're called "objects". Don't take this the wrong way, but perhaps you're not quite ready to go into plugin development yet.

Comment: I know that they're objects. I need to know exactly how they call a function.

Answer (score 2):

These are just objects,

You can define them like this,

```
var x = { 'z' : 100, 'c' : 200 }
```

you can pass them into a function like this,

```
doSomething(x);
```

and you can use them in a function like this,

```
function dosomething(x) {
  var z = x.z;
  var x = x.c;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I didn't know that you could actually pass objects through functions and use the object & it's properties and whatnot within it.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You mean [objects](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Object)?

To add a function or create a plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function(object1, object2){
  // Here 'this' is the set of matched elements
}
```